# Webpack, new chunk is loading in with wrong path

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to chunk my app  - attempting to follow webpacks guide on how-to (https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html). So I have a seperate chunk set up for my app, I can see that webpack is generating `1.bundle.js` in my build folder, however it is pasting it onto my `index.html` with an incorrect path, and in my console I see the fetch error for the `1.bundle.js` file.

So my webpack config looks like so (im just using the webpack:dev for now):

```
 return {
    dev: {
        entry: {
            index: './client/app.jsx'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'dist', 'client'),
            publicPath: "/dist/client/",
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            fallback: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "process.env": {
                    "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("dev")
                }
            })
        ]
    },
```

and in my index.html I manually add `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` and that has been working great. It looks like when this builds now, webpack is applying its own script tag on my index like so

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="/dist/client/1.bundle.js"></script>
```

However this path is incorrect, it should just be `src="1.bundle.js"`. I have tried tweaking the path and publicPath but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to have webpack add the correct path? Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should change `publicPath` for this snippet:

```
publicPath: "/"
```

It will always serve your chunks from root path.

Comment: I have three config files : Prod,Dev and server. There is no publicPath property prod config or base config. Should I add one in `output` object?

Comment: When writing a library, is it ok to set this to the local relative path to the `dist` directory? e.g. `config.output.publicPath = "./dist/";`? Will this interfere with the consumers of my library?

Answer (score 15):

Even though it is answered and accepted, I am providing additional helpful info for others with similar problems.

There are two different purposes for which the 2 parameters are used.

1. **Output:path :** The directory the bundle files mentioned in entry section are saved into. For example, the bundle.js for the 'entry' entry you had mentioned. In this case, it will be saved in `webconfigfolder+"../../dist/client"` folder.
2. **Output: publicPath:** The directory prefix that is added to refer to a module when accessed from browser. 0.bundle.js is an unnamed chunk created by code splitting. It will be placed in the output:path mentioned above but will be referred in your html using the public path.

So,if your files as in this case is stored in `/dist/client` folder, but the index.htm is served in `/dist/client`, you should give the public path as `./.` If htm is served from `/dist`, the public path should be given as `./client/.`

The public path is useful for chunks created for async loading which are called from browser dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I can't get it to work properly. If I set `publicPath` then `0.bundle.js` loads properly, but images and fonts referenced in CSS don't. If I don't set it then the images in CSS load, but not the async js bundle.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have given reference to `publicPath`. So it will try to load the script from this `publicPath` though the file is not present there.

Removing `publicPath` can resolve the error